# Android time and date picker in one (iOS equivalent)

Tags: html, datepicker, uipickerview, timepicker, android-datepicker

I am building an HTML5 coded app that will be wrapped for both android and iPhone.

I have a button that should evoke the date/time picker. On iOS this is easy as the picker already exists in one

[image]

Android has date and time picker in two different pickers.
Do you have any examples of combining them? Or introducing a flow going from one picker to the other without having two different buttons on the start screen to select from?

What I want is 1 button on the screen: "Select date and time" -> Opens combined picker (or picker flow)
I don't want 2 buttons: "Select date" "Select time" -> here you need to open two pickers independently. One for each button.

Any suggestions, examples and so on are more than welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Every browser renders the native date and time pickers slightly differently.

If you're looking for a consistent solution, you can take a look at the [Mobiscroll Date & Time Scroller](http://mobiscroll.com/component/datetime).

It supports both Android and iOS, and it's themable, so you have even more control on how it looks & feels.